# How to make column updatable in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to make a banking system with Java. The user should be able to type in a number in a text field, and deposit said amount of money into the bank account. I would like to then update the account balance in the Microsot Access database.

I currently have this:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//User//IdeaProjects//Database4.accdb")) {
    Statement users = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet sr = users.executeQuery("Select * from Registrations");
    Boolean duplicate = false;
    while (sr.next()) {
        if (userID.equals(sr.getString(2))) {
            match = sr;
            duplicate = true;
            System.out.println("Welcome " + match.getString(2));
            System.out.println("Your balance is " + match.getString(3));
            break;
        }

    }
}
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == depositButton) {
        String depositString = depositField.getText();
        int depositAmount = Integer.parseInt(depositString);
        try {
            System.out.println(match.getInt(3) + depositAmount);
            match.updateInt("AccBalance", match.getInt(3) + depositAmount);
            match.updateRow();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to do this, I get the error 'attempt to assign to non-updatable column'.
I'm very new to Java and tried looking online to find fixes for this issue but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Why are you looping over your entire table to get on row: use prepared statements with a `WHERE` clause to select the record(s) your interested in. Similarly, don't try to update through a result set, use an `UPDATE` statement. Also, please provide a [mre]. You don't show what `match` is, nor the exception stacktrace, but probably it is a non-updatable result set (which is the default, read the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update)).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//mghosh22//IdeaProjects//Database4.accdb")) {
    // Query example UPDATE user SET balance = 10000 WHERE user.id = 1;
    PreparedStatement updateBalance = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE <table> SET balance = ? WHERE <wich row update>");
    // For each query parameter, set a value to execute the same
    // preparedStatement.setParameterType(countEach?StartingWithOne, yourQueryParameter);
    updateBalance.setDouble(1, 10,000.00);
    
    // Execute update return the amount of rows your query affected, how we are talking about account balance, the number of rows affected may be ever one
    if (updateBalance.executeUpdate() == 1) {
        System.out.println("Row updated");
    }
}
```